# What do the execution policies in std::copy_n really mean?

Tags: c++, multithreading, copy, c++20, simd

I just discovered that `std::copy_n` provides overloads for different execution policies. Yet I find [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) quite hard to understand here as (I suppose) it is kept very general. So I have difficulties putting together what actually goes on.

1. I don't really understand the explanation of the first policy:

> The execution policy type used as a unique type to disambiguate
> parallel algorithm overloading and require that a parallel algorithm's
> execution may not be parallelized. *The invocations of element access
> functions in parallel algorithms* invoked with this policy (usually
> specified as std::execution::seq) are indeterminately sequenced in the
> calling thread.

To my understanding this means that we don't parallelize (multithread) here and each element access is sequential like in strcpy. This basically means to me that one thread runs through the function and I'm done. But then there is

> invocations of element access functions in parallel algorithms.

What now? Are there still paralell algorithms? How?

2. The second execution policy states that:

> Any such invocations executing in the same thread are indeterminately
> sequenced with respect to each other.

What I imagine that means is this: Each thread starts at a different position, e.g. the container is split up into multiple segments and each thread copies one of those segments. The threads are created by the library just to run the algorithm. Am I correct in assuming so?

3. From the third policy:

> The invocations of element access functions in parallel algorithms
> invoked with this policy are permitted to execute in an unordered
> fashion in unspecified threads, and unsequenced with respect to one
> another within each thread.

Does this mean the above mentioned container "segments" need not be copied one after another but can be copied in random fashion? If so, why is this so important to justify an extra policy? When I have multiple threads they will need to be somewhat intermixed to keep synchronisation on a minimum no?

So here's my probably incorrect current understanding of the policies. Please correct me!

- **sequenced_policy**: 1 thread executes the algorithm and copies everything from A - Z.
- **parallel_policy**: Lib creates new threads specifically for copying, whereas each thread's copied segment has to follow the other (sequenced)?
- **parallel_unsequenced_policy**: try to multithread *and* SIMD. Copied segments can be intermixed by thread (it doesn't matter where you start).
- **unsequenced_policy**: Try to use SIMD but only singlethreaded.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *from A - Z*. The order of operations is not mandatory. Esp. **indeterminately sequenced** means the operations (copying in this case) can happen in any order, and doesn't have to be in the 'sequential' order starting with iterator `fiirst`. However they will happen one after the other, i.e. with sequence points in between.

Answer (score 3):

Your summary of the basic idea of each policy is basically correct.

> Does this mean the above mentioned container "segments" need not be copied one after another but can be copied in random fashion? If so, why is this so important to justify an extra policy?

The extra policies for `unsequenced_policy` and `parallel_unsequenced_policy` are necessary because they impose an extra requirement on calling code<sup>1</sup>:

> The
> behavior of a program is undefined if it invokes a vectorization-unsafe standard library function from user code
> called from a execution::unsequenced_policy algorithm.

[and a matching restriction for  `parallel_unsequenced_policy`.]

These four execution policies are used for algorithms in general. The mention of user code called from execution of the algorithm *mostly* applies to things like `std::for_each`, or `std::generate`, where you tell the algorithm to invoke a function. Here's one of the examples from the standard:

```cpp
int a[] = {0,1};
std::vector<int> v;
std::for_each(std::execution::par, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int i) {
v.push_back(i*2+1); // incorrect: data race
});
```

This particular example shows a problem created by parallel execution--you might have two threads trying to invoke `push_back` on `v` concurrently, giving a data race.

If you use `for_each` with one of the unsequenced policies, that imposes a further constraint on what your code can do.

When we look specifically at `std::copy_n`, that's probably less of a problem as a rule, because we're not passing it some code to be invoked. Well, we're not doing so directly, anyway. In reality, we are potentially doing so indirectly though. `std::copy_n` uses the assignment operator for the item being copied. So, for example, consider something like this:

```cpp
class foo {
    static int copy_count;
    int data;
public:
    foo &operator=(foo const &other) {
        data = other.data;
        ++copy_count;
    }
};

foo::int copy_count;

std::vector<foo> a;
std::vector<foo> b;

// code to fill a with data goes here

std::copy_n(std::execution::par, a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b));
```

Our copy assignment operator accesses `copy_count` without synchronization. If we specify sequential execution, that's fine, but if we specify parallel execution we're now (potentially) invoking it concurrently on two or more threads, so we have a data race.

I'd probably have to work harder to put together a somewhat coherent reason for an assignment operator to do something that was vectorizaton-unsafe, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

## Summary

We have four separate execution policies because each imposes unique constraints on what you can do in your code. In the specific cases of `std::copy` or `std::copy_n`, those constraints apply primarily to the assignment operator for the items in the collection being copied.

---

1. N4835, section [algorithms.parallel.exec]